# How to rollback to a previous revision and keep going

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I made some changes to a project that I need to take out.  The easiest way is to rollback to the project 3 days ago and start from there.

How do I make that revision the new head of the project in ToutoiseSVN?

Comment: As for most tasks, there are several options on how you can achieve this. The TortoiseSVN docs explain them [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To revert to a previous revision you do not actually revert to that revision - you create a new changeset, which - when committed - will revert your source code to look like that revision.

You can do it by marking a couple of commits in the log, right click, and select "revert changes from this revision".

And don't worry, nothing will really happen until you commit that changeset.

Comment: What he said.  The trick is, as  mentioned, **"revert changes from this revision"**.. which gets really confusing since "revert to this revision" is an option.